# JQuery: Dynamically Remove Elements (Isolate Function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

fiddle - http://jsbin.com/oloriTo/1/edit

Removing elements isn't the problem, but when I click on the remove false button (class is .rf) I want to no longer remove elements, unless the remove true (class is .rt) button is clicked.

Currently when I click the remove true element it does as expected. (demos a bit crummy but it gets the point across) When I click on the remove false button I can still click on elements within the .container div and remove them, which is not suppose to happen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var enabled = false;
  $('.rt').click(function() {
    enabled = true;

    if (enabled === true) {
      $('.container *').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
      });
    } else {
      enabled = false;
    }
  });

  $('.rf').click(function() {
    enabled = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: The condition is pointless, `enabled` will always be true as you're setting it to true on the line above?

Comment: The var for enabled is set to false by default. When the button remove true is clicked enabled is turned to true and then false when the remove false button is clicked.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you set it to, you always reset it to true on the line right before the condition, so it's like doing `if (true === true)`, it's always true, and you just keep piling on event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the remove code inside the set enabled code. Break it out and have it look at the variable set by `.rf` and `.rt`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var enabled = false;
  $('.rt').click(function() {
    enabled = true;
  });

  $('.rf').click(function() {
    enabled = false;
  });
  $('.container').on('mousedown touchstart', '*',function() {
      if (enabled)      
        $(this).remove();
      return false;
   });
});
```